# VW Jetta 2000 ECU swap

Tags: vw, electronic-control-module, jetta, engine-swap

I've read the forums and my question isn't answered. I have swapped my 2.0 to 1.6 in my 2000 Jetta still using my 2.0 ecu for the 1.6l engine. Is it safe? How will the fuel economy be and any effects?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to account for ... but to answer the question "*Is it safe?*", by all means it should be. It's not going to explode, but you could be washing down your cylinder walls with excess fuel.

As long as it is running fine, there shouldn't be a huge issue. As I previously stated, there are still some potential *gotchas* you need to be aware of.

- If you installed the injectors from the 2.0L onto the 1.6L engine, you are more than likely over fueling and making the engine run rich. If so, this will most likely plug your catalytic converter in no time.
- If there is unburnt fuel in the combustion chamber from being too rich, it could also be washing down your cylinders (as I stated before). This removes the oil from the cylinder walls and makes it basically metal (rings) on metal (cylinder wall), which can eat your rings up in no time.
- If you're running the injectors which came in the 1.6L to begin with, you shouldn't be over fueling it by too much if at all.

The basis of all of this is, you really need to have the ECU tuned professionally so that you aren't creating other issues. If you can find a 1.6L ECU which matches the engine and the Jetta where you're at, it may be the easiest route, but it might bring other issues (thinking security).

On a side note, I looked to find the difference in injectors for the 1.6 vs the 2.0 engine and couldn't find the 1.6 specs anywhere ... because we don't import any VW's of that era into the US with 1.6L engines. I took a look to see you are out of Ghana, so I guess VW must do something with them there ;-)

Comment: Many car manufacturers "dumped" older engines no longer valid (ie meeting emissions) in the US and EU into other countries with lower, or no, emissions standards (perhaps even paid bribes - who knows... But the excess engine stock definitely went somewhere...